# Django: deleting a one-to-one related field in post_delete causes recursion

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, recursion, django-models

I have a model, say `Model1` that has a OneToOne related field `Model2`. There is a `post_delete` signal connected method of `Model1` that calls `instance.model2.delete()`, and very infrequently, this causes a recursive call back to the `Model1.post_delete()`. I've followed the stack trace, here is the recursion on Django 1.8 (most recent last):

```
File "myapp/models.py", line 645, in post_delete
    instance.model2.delete()
File "django/db/models/base.py", line 896, in delete
    collector.delete()
File "django/db/models/deletion.py", line 314, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
File "django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "myapp/models.py", line 645, in post_delete
    instance.model2.delete()
File "django/db/models/base.py", line 896, in delete
    collector.delete()
File "django/db/models/deletion.py", line 314, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
File "django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
```

After following it many times in debug, and testing extensively with automation, I have come to the conclusion that the problem is that

```
File "django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
```

is erroneously being called from

```
File "django/db/models/deletion.py", line 314, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
```

somehow. What could possibly be going on?

EDIT here's the post_delete signaled method:

```
class Model1:
    model2 = models.OneToOneField(Model2, null=True, editable=False)
    ...
    @classmethod
    def post_delete(cls, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance.model2.delete()
        except Model2.DoesNotExist:
            pass  # This can happen if the model2 was never created

signals.post_delete.connect(Model1.post_delete, sender=Model1)
```

Comment: Post your models and post_delete signals to make this easier.

Comment: You mean the method that's called on post_delete?

Comment: Ah, so you didn't define your own `post_delete` signal did you? Got it. If you want help we're going to need to see the code that is actually triggering this recursion. Or are you manually attempting to delete something through the admin console?

Comment: Posted in an edit

Comment: What do your models look like? I assume `Model1` and `Model2` have a `OneToOne` field linking them but depending on who has the field that could explain your recursion.

Comment: Everything's in `Model1`